# Jquery - How to output "$(this).val()" within html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. I'd like to output input value but it appears as "$(this).val()" in html.

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="$(this).val()" /> ');
```

How should I change this code in order to output the value selected jquery object has?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation?

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="' + $(this).val() + '" /> ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything within the double quotes will be outputted as text. To output the javascript result, you need to use concatenation.

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="'+$(this).val()+'" /> ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Concatenation. and do move it outside double quotes. **Else it will be just as text NOT javascript**

It will do the job :

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="'+$(this).val()+'" /> ');
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="'+$(this).val()+'" /> ');
```

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of events (OnClick, OnMouseOver, etc), the contents of an attribute are interpreted as just text--not Javascript. In order to have the `value` of your hidden input field contain `$(this).val()`, you'll need to concatenate the javascript with the HTML. This means you're looking for:

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="' + $(this).val() + '" /> ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use String Concatenation to output your Value,

```
bulkEdit.append('<input type="hidden" name="Post[id][]" value="' + $(this).val() + '" /> ');
```

More about String Concatenation: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc